# Elevation is not working on both jelly bean and Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-layout

**Elevation Not Working,**
I am working on a android application with *minSdk 16*. When I try to use elevation property the android studio visualizer shows the elevation properly but when I run the app on both emulator(Marshmallow) and device(Jelly Bean and lollipop) it is not showing the elevation. The action bar and FAB elevation is working fine on lollipop and above(fab elevation on lower devices too).
*I already tried lots of the things that found on the web including stack overflow, for now I am using `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"` to get the elevation, but it is not solving the actual problem.* Can anybody help me.

Comment: To which view are you setting the elevation? Post the XML.

Comment: I tried on different views including TextView, TimePicker, and in LinearLayout

Comment: You have to use the AppCompat version of the view. For example instead of TextView you have to use AppCompatTextView and instead of LinearLayout you have to use LinearLayoutCompat. Not sure about the timepicker.

Comment: Thanks Lakshan it works, Thank you very much.